# is there any time constraint in responding server

Tags: ajax

For an ajax query, is there any time constraint for server to respond? if yes how can i set this time? this should be happen in javascript , front end , where if a problem happen and server does not respond an error is occurred . In my code , By this URL , a function execute and some operations are done . Surly these operations have no problem but take a long time , and message "error is occurred" is shown .
`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        
      $.ajax({    
           url : "/ajaxUpdateOrInsertReportResult",    
           type : "GET"',                               
           data : "projectId="'+projectId,    
           success: successFn,    
           error : function(xml, error) {    
           alert(error is occurred);    
              }    
       });    
   });      
   function successFn(result){    
         alert("update done successfully")    
   }
```

`

Comment: What `console.log(error)` would display?

Comment: As my code shows , in error function "error is occurred" message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the $.ajax [doc](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) Here is the details.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "your/url",
    error: function(){
        // will fire when timeout is reached
    },
    success: function(){
        //do something
    },
    timeout: 3000 // sets timeout to 3 seconds
});
```

Also You can use

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/getData',
    timeout:3000 //3 second timeout
}).done(function(){
    //do something
});
```

Comment: many thanks . what is timeout default value   If not specified ؟